# Interpretation of PARAFAC/TUCKER components for factor mode?

Tags: pca, svd

I am working on my thesis at the moment and I'm stuck...
I would need to use a multimode-PCA method like Parafac/Tucker-N.
My task is to find any deviating structure from the data which is in 3-mode.
My data has individuals(mode1), measured variables(mode2) and those variables are measured in time so I have occasions(mode3).
I understand that the interpretation of the components becomes a real challenge for your mental health. But what I really don't understand is that how come there can be components for the "factor" mode1? That mode only contains different individuals (and is assumed that they are all independent from each other).
So my question is that what it means to have more than 1 component for this mode?
Any help is much appreciated thanks!

Comment: I don't know this method, but if it is based on an SVD, that outputs eigenvectors for both rows & columns simultaneously.